# How to check the uniqueness of an attribute in an XML file

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq, unique, xmlreader

If I have an XML file and I want to check the **uniqueness** of the attribute `id` of each element like the following document:

```
<classes columns="id,name,short,classroomids,teacherid,grade,customfield1">
  <class id="0ini" name="Initial Class" short="Init" teacherid="" classroomids="" grade="" customfield1="0"/>
  <class id="*2" name="A1" short="A1" teacherid="" classroomids="" grade="" customfield1="30"/>
  <class id="*3" name="A2" short="A2" teacherid="" classroomids="" grade="" customfield1=""/>
</classes>
```

I want to check that the `id` attribute is **unique**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `HashSet` to check for uniqueness.

```cs
var set = new HashSet<string>();
foreach(var id in doc.Descendants()
                 .Select(a => a.Attribute("id").Value))
  if(!set.Add(id))
    throw new Exception("Not Unique");
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you can't add it to the schema, you could use LINQ to XML for that:

```cs
var allIds = doc.Descendants()
                .Select(x => x.Attribute("id"))
                .Where(x => x != null)
                .Select(x => x.Value)
                .ToList();
var allDistinct = allIds.Count == allIds.Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: hmmm,thanks a lot .is this for one element or for all elements:
the xml file like this :

Comment: @just_name: It's the whole document - that's what the Descendants call does.

Answer (score 1):

In code or what? You could always add XML Scheme or DTD and check validity (you can define attr to be unique).

i.e. write XMLScheme or DTD (DTD is simpler, but less flexible), to define structure of your XML. Define there that attribute `id` of tag `class` is unique (is `ID` in DTD). In code, check if given XML is valid against XML Sheme / DTD

Tuts for XML Schemas `Unique` and DTDs `ID`:

[XML XSD Schema - Enforce Unique Attribute Values in Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541305/xml-xsd-schema-enforce-unique-attribute-values-in-schema)

http://www.featureblend.com/dtd-unique-attribute.html

and search for validating xml in code.

Comment: Could U give me an example or link to what u want to say?

Comment: see edit. BTW, `colums` in `classes` seems excessive and wrong to me. Defining what attributes tags have is document structure, not data - it should be in schema/dtd, not in parent element.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = XElement.Parse (@"
<classes columns='id,name,short,classroomids,teacherid,grade,customfield1'>
   <class id='0ini' name='Initial Class' short='Init' teacherid='' classroomids='' grade='' customfield1='0'/>
   <class id='*2' name='A1' short='A1' teacherid='' classroomids='' grade='' customfield1='30'/>
   <class id='*3' name='A2' short='A2' teacherid='' classroomids='' grade='' customfield1=''/>
</classes>");       

bool containsDuplicates = data.Descendants().GroupBy(desc=>desc.Attribute("id").Value).Any(grp=>grp.Count()>1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This XPath returns a boolean value indicating whether or not there are repeated `@id` values:

```
boolean(//*/@id[.=following::*/@id])
```

Applied with the [XPathEvaluate method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341675.aspx):

```
XDocument d = XDocument.Parse(xml);
bool hasDuplicateId = (bool)d.XPathEvaluate("boolean(//*/@id[.=following::*/@id])");
```