# What XPath expression should I use in xs:field to select element content?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xsd-1.0

I am aware that in general one uses `/the/path/to/a/node/text()` to extract a string value. That has not been sufficient to solve my problem.

I am using XML Schema version 1.0 to define some document types. I am trying to create a very simple `keywords` section for a document type. So I first create a very simple complex type.

```
<xs:complexType name="KeywordsList">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="tag" type="xs:token" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

So now I have a type that can contain a list of any number of elements containing `xs:token` values. **My problem begins with the question of how to forbid duplicates**.

I have used `xs:key` and `xs:unique` pretty often for this very trivial task, but I have only ever done it for attribute values or more deeply nested elements. For example, if the keyword values were stored in an attribute named `value` instead I know I could do something like this.

```
...
<xs:element name="keywords" type="KeywordsList">
    <xs:unique name="KeywordsListUnique">
        <xs:selector xpath="child::tag"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@value"/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
...
```

**What really confuses me is that `<xs:selector xpath="child::tag"/>` is enough for the XML parser to locate the values, but I am required to include at least one `xs:field` tag**.

At first I thought I should specify `<xs:field xpath="text()"/>` to reference the text content of the node, but when I do that I get an error message from [OxygenXML](https://www.oxygenxml.com/).

> c-general-xpath: The expression 'text()' is not valid with respect to the XPath subset supported by XML Schema.

I get similar messages for `child::text()`, `./text()`, and a few other similar ones. I have gotten rid of the error messages by using a single dot to reference the current node, but I don't know if `.` is the correct expression to use.

**So what should I put in the `xs:field` tag?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, indeed, to use `<xs:field xpath="."/>` as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300203/unique-element-in-xsd-sequence).